# Does weak $L^2$ approximation implies $L^2$ approximation under a condition similar to convexity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

(Cross posted from Math StackExchange: [Does weak $L^2$ approximation implies $L^2$ approximation under a condition similar to convexity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831754/does-weak-l2-approximation-implies-l2-approximation-under-a-condition-simi))

Assume $(\Omega, \mu)$ is a probability space. Consider a class of functions $S$ all contained in the unit ball of $L^\infty(\Omega, \mu)$. Let $f \in L^\infty(\Omega, \mu)$ be contained in the weak $L^2$ closure of $S$. Now, if $S$ is convex, Hahn-Banach implies $f$ is also contained in the $L^2$ norm closure of $S$. I’m wondering if the following condition on $S$, which seems similar in spirit to convexity, is also sufficient to imply $f$’s containment in the $L^2$ norm closure of $S$:

For any countable measurable partition $(A_i)$ of $\Omega$ and corresponding collection $(s_i)$ of elements of $S$, the function $\sum_{i \in I} s_i|_{A_i}$ is in $S$. (The sum here is simply a shorthand meaning joining together these functions defined on pairwise disjoint domains.)

Any help or reference is appreciated.

---

Edit: As pointed out by @NarutakaOZAWA’s comment, this is not true in general. However, I’m mostly interested in the case where $S$ consists of real-valued functions. Does a counterexample also exist in that case?

Comment: The set $S$ of unitary functions contains zero in the weak $L^2$ closure.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA You’re right. Guess this isn’t true in general. Do you think a similar counterexample could exist if we also assume all functions in $S$ are real-valued? The unitary example doesn’t seem easily adaptable to that.

Comment: The same holds for the real case. For example, iid Rademacher variables are orthonormal and hence contain zero in the weak $L^2$ closure.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Ah, so the set of all self-adjoint unitaries would be a counterexample. Thank you so much!